# How do I install libgnomeprint in Debian testing?

Tags: debian

I installed Debian testing (jessie) and put this in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian testing main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
```

I want to install a third-party piece of software that requires `libgnomeprint`, but I can't seem to find it in the repository. I used `apt-cache search libgnomeprint` and `apt-cache search gnome | grep print`, but no luck. I [searched the repositories online](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libgnomeprint) , but no luck.

According to a changelog it was [removed from Debian testing](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/libgnomeprint/+publishinghistory) (I think), so if I'm interpreting that correctly, it's not available in testing at all? Is there any way to install it? I don't want to just add a repository for another version of Debian, like stable, because I'll get package conflicts that way.

Is it dangerous if I just find a deb of v2.2 somewhere and install it? I don't want that to put me in dependency hell, or will it not?

If it's relevant, I'm not actually using *gnome* as my DE; I just need this one package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [removals file](http://ftp-master.debian.org/removals.txt), it was removed from future Debian at the request of the maintainer. The reason cited is that the library is obsolete.

It still exists in current stable. Adding stable sources to a testing system is fairly safe, since all versions in testing should be the same or newer. The risk is minimal because `apt` will never downgrade packages unless explicitly told to do so (unlike upgrades). Add a source line for `wheezy` and then install it via `apt-get`.

Comment: I added a source line that specifically referenced `stable main`, installed the package, and everything looks good. Thank you!